# How to use XmlReader ReadToFollowing when there are various numbers of same nodes ? (c#)

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I don't know if the title was clear but here is my problem. I have an xml file like this :

```
<pdv id="69330005" latitude="4578181.32121" longitude="500540.118325" cp="69330" pop="R">
<adresse>80 Rue Joseph Desbois</adresse>
<ville>MEYZIEU</ville>
<ouverture debut="01:00" fin="01:00" saufjour=""/>
<services>
  <service>Station de lavage</service>
  <service>Vente de gaz domestique</service>
  <service>Automate CB</service>
</services>
<prix nom="Gazole" id="1" maj="2017-04-18 08:44:42" valeur="1.233"/>
<prix nom="SP95" id="2" maj="2017-04-18 08:44:42" valeur="1.398"/>
<prix nom="SP98" id="6" maj="2017-04-18 08:44:42" valeur="1.454"/>
</pdv>
```

I want to put in a string the attributes "nom" and "valeur" of all the nodes "prix". But at the moment I just manage to get the first "prix" node and his attributes but can't get the others. How should I do ?

```
 public string parseXML(double latitude, double longitude, float distance)
    {
        string name = "";
        float lat, lng;
        bool isIn = false;
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("PrixCarburants_instantane.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Name == "pdv" && reader.HasAttributes && reader.GetAttribute("latitude") != string.Empty && reader.GetAttribute("longitude") != string.Empty)
                {
                    lat = float.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("latitude"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100000;
                    lng = float.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("longitude"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100000;
                    if(DistanceTo(latitude, longitude, lat, lng)<distance) //check if the place that I am reading in the file is at a maximum distance of the point I put in parameters
                    {

                        isIn = true;
                    }
                    if (isIn)//only read "prix" node if the place is in the distance I chose
                    {
                        reader.ReadToFollowing("prix");
                        name += reader.GetAttribute("nom") + " " +reader.GetAttribute("valeur");


                        isIn= false;
                    }

                }



            } // end while
        }

        return name;

    }
```

By the way, the number of "prix" nodes is variable between 0 and 6.

Comment: Do you *definitely* need to use XmlReader? If you could possibly use `XDocument` (LINQ to XML) it would make your life much, much simpler.

Comment: Hi, my file is more than 150k lines long, and I read that it was better to use XmlReader instead of XDocument. Or maybe 150k is not too long ?

Comment: Are you in a particularly memory-constrained environment? It sounds like it could fit into memory pretty simply...

Comment: Well not really but it's just the beginning of the file treatment, I am going to do a lot more after, so I thought it was better to use something that doesn't take a lot of memory.

Comment: Why not start with the simplest thing that can work, and then do more complicated work when that's proved to be needed? That's my normal approach.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at XDocument, I hope it won't be too slow  :p. Thank you for your advices !